# Warning message while using the Scanner class

Tags: java, warnings

In this Java program, I want to input (string) values from the keyboard and print the string values.

A **warning message** pops up on LINE 8 when the program is executed. The **warning message** on LINE 8 is

*"Resource leak: 'sc' is never closed."*

The code:

```
package practice_space;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Name_Less
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("type something");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String w_1 = sc.next();
        String w_2 = sc.next();
        String w_3 = sc.next();
        System.out.println("word_1 = "+w_1);
        System.out.println("word_2 = "+w_2);
        System.out.println("word_3 = "+w_3);
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically whenever you work with any kind of file I/O (in any language not just java) you want to make sure that your code releases its handle on that file resource so you don't have deadlock conditions.

In the case of your example this is pretty simple fix of

```
package practice_space;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Name_Less
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("type something");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String w_1 = sc.next();
        String w_2 = sc.next();
        String w_3 = sc.next();
        System.out.println("word_1 = "+w_1);
        System.out.println("word_2 = "+w_2);
        System.out.println("word_3 = "+w_3);
        sc.close(); // Finished using the file so close the scanner
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `Scanner.close()` method at the end of the method:

```
...
System.out.println("word_3 = "+w_3);
sc.close();
...
```